# Get record with MAX date

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api

I have a data looks like this from my database. My report will have 2 parameters, `Start Date` and `End Date`.

[image: SQL Query]

For example if the user select `Start Date = 1/1/2015` and `End Date = 12/31/2015`, the report should return user `TierCode = Privilege`.

I've achieve this using Stored Procedure. But the performance is an issues here as I couldn't use Extract Data.

```
SELECT
    m.MemberID,
    ty.TierCode AS TierCodeTY,
    ly.TierCode AS TierCodeLY
FROM
    Tangs_dim_Member m LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT TierCode, MemberID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MemberID ORDER BY SnapshotDate DESC) AS i
        FROM dw_Tangs_MonthlySnapshot
        WHERE SnapshotDate >= @StartDate AND SnapshotDate <= @EndDate
    ) ty
ON
    ty.MemberID = m.MemberID AND ty.i = 1 LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT TierCode, MemberID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MemberID ORDER BY SnapshotDate DESC) AS i
        FROM dw_Tangs_MonthlySnapshot
        WHERE SnapshotDate >= DATEADD(year,-1,@StartDate) AND SnapshotDate <= DATEADD(year,-1,@EndDate)
    ) ly
ON
    ly.MemberID = m.MemberID AND ly.i = 1
```

[image: Tableau Dashboard]

How can I achieve above report without using Stored Procedure. Calculated field is fine as long I can use Views / Custom Query / Tables + Extract Data. So the data will be filtered at Tableau instead at the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the last inserted record by adding Ordered by [date] 
and get just first one by adding [Limit 1] in the sql query

hope that help you

Comment: My report will have `This Year` and `Last Year`. Order date is just fine, just not `Limit`. Because I need to get all records and determine the `Last Year` from Tableau by using calculated field `If [Date] >= [Start Date] And [Date] <= [End Date] Then [MemberID] Else NULL End`